# Is this tafseer of الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ correct?

Tags: tafseer, quran-translation, translation

الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ

All praises are to Allah

*"All the praises - present, past and future - are entitled to God alone, because He is the Creator of all things and He is the Bestower of all blessings, whether He may give them directly or indirectly. For example, the heat or light received from the sunshine, is, in fact, a gift of the Sun. Similarly, the original source of all blessings and bounties is Allah though they may come through some intermediate agency.* 
**Note**: 
"All kinds of praises" is not correct translation, because there is no limit of God's praises."

**Tafseer-E-Usmani by Shabbir Ahmad Usmani.**

> Is this tafseer of الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation "all praises to Allah" mean the praises of human beings like you and me. 
But in this hadith it doesn't mean that our praises are limited. You could pray sunnah prayers, perform tahajjud and dua's, build a mosque. 
All praises to Allah means it comes from the people that intend it to Allah(swt).
I think you confused it with blessing from Allah to the people. When then you're right that Allah's blessings are indeed limitless.

Comment: This looks like a copy paste as the question doesn't include any hadith so what are you referring to by "But in this hadith it doesn't mean that our praises are limited. You could pray sunnah prayers, perform tahajjud and dua's, build a mosque."? You should add references to all your quotes.

Comment: It was more like syntactical issue rather than a islamic related issue.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: So I didn't put any sources and I assure you it's not copy-pasted since it's a direct answer about the mistake the OP'er made. Did you read my answer?